# AppwriteException: null, File bytes must be provided for Flutter web (0)

Tags: flutter, dart, appwrite

I was trying to create a file in Appwrite Storage Bucket but without success.

I'm using the packages:
appwrite: ^8.0.2
image_picker: ^1.0.2

the image is being collected by the image picker because I can use it in the program with Image.network() but for some reason the InputFile cannot get this path and this error occurs.

I tried every way to make it work but I couldn't.

[My Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5YVr.png)

```
Storage storage = Storage(client);

image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

if (image != null) {
  imagePath = image!.path;

  var imageInput = InputFile.fromPath(
    path: imagePath,
    filename: 'teste.png',
  );

  var result = await storage.createFile(
    bucketId: bucketId,
    fileId: ID.unique(),
    file: imageInput,
  );
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: there is the code

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter Web, you'll need to use `InputFile.fromBytes()` instead of `InputFile.fromPath()`:

```dart
final imageInput = InputFile.fromBytes(
  filename: image.name,
  bytes: await image.readAsBytes(),
);
```

This is because the path you get on web is the Blob/Object URL and not an actual path that Flutter can read.

Additional reference:

- Playground for Flutter: https://github.com/appwrite/playground-for-flutter/blob/ad30fb232a223e118c9429ac1df75f856b6a1d9d/lib/main.dart#L97-L100
- GitHub Issue: https://github.com/appwrite/sdk-for-flutter/issues/174

Comment: I am upgrading 0.12.x to 0.13.4. And facing similar error. I am in the mobile but throwing that kind of error. Do I need to change to bytes too ?